# Uploading multiple files via PHP and posting information to MYSQL database

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to upload multiple files to the server, while inputting upload information into a database. For some reason only the first or last file is being put into the DB but I can not for the life of me figure out why!

Any help appreciated - thanks!

```
public function processNewUploads()
{
    $language = OW::getLanguage();
    $osuploadBOL = OSUPLOAD_BOL_Service::getInstance();

    //Loop through each file that was uploaded  
    for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']); $i++){


        /* check if there is a file in the array
for($i=0; $i < count($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name']); $i++){            
        if(!is_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$i]))
        {
            OW::getFeedback()->error($language->text('osupload','no_files_selected'));
            OW::getApplication()->redirect(OW::getRouter()->urlForRoute('base_index'));
        } */


        //Check to see if there was an error
        if($_FILES['uploads']['error'][$i] > 0){
            $error = $_FILES['uploads']['error'][$i];
        }else{
            $error = 0;
        }

        //Prepare information to enter into database//

        //If the user is logged in then get the userId
        if(OW::getUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
            $fileOwner = OW::getUser()->getId();
        } else {
            $fileOwner = 0;
        }

        //Get the IP of the uploader
        $fileOwnerIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        //Get the raw file name
        $rawFileName = $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$i];

        //Get the unique file name
        $uniqueFileName = uniqid('',true);

        //Get the upload time
        $uploadTimeStamp = time();

        //Get the file extension
        $fileExtension = explode(".", $_FILES['uploads']['name'][$i]);
        $n = count($fileExtension) - 1;
        $fileExtension = '.'.strtolower($fileExtension[$n]);

        //Get the size of the file
        $fileSize = $_FILES['uploads']['size'][$i];

        //Get the display name of the file
        $fileDisplayName = $rawFileName;

        //Insert the file information into the database
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . OSUPLOAD_BOL_OsuploadDao::getInstance()->getTableName() . " (fileOwner,fileOwnerIp,rawFileName,uniqueFileName,uploadTimeStamp,fileExtension,fileSize,fileDisplayName,error)
        VALUES ('$fileOwner','$fileOwnerIp','$rawFileName','$uniqueFileName.$fileExtension','$uploadTimeStamp','$fileExtension','$fileSize','$fileDisplayName','$error')";

        OW::getDbo()->Insert($sql);

        if(!$error > 0){
            //Move the new upload as long as there was not an error with it
            $fileToMove = $_FILES['uploads']['tmp_name'][$i];
            $osuploadBOL->moveNewUpload($fileToMove,$uniqueFileName,$fileExtension);
            continue;
        }else{
            //If there was an error just go to the next file
            continue;
        }
    }
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<input name="uploads[]" id="uploads" type="file" multiple="">
```

Comment: Each file element on the upload form has to have a unique name (or be an array) or else the key in the `$_FILES` array will be overwritten with the last file. You might just be able to add `[]` to the end of the name and loop over everything under the name.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not sure exactly what you mean - I thought if you upload multiple files they would be in an array anyway? How would I put them into an array if not?

Comment: What @JonathanKuhn is getting at is the `<input>` name attribute, so `$_FILES['uploads']` is the name of one file and is represented in form html as `<input type="file" name="uploads">` otherwise use array like `<input type="file" name="uploads[]">`, note the `uploads[]` as array. After that do a `var_dump($_FILES)` to see structure

Comment: Thanks @gwillie In the HTML the [] (see edited question) but how would I access / loop through all of them using the code in my question? I must be so close to doing it!

Answer (score 0):

This is just a quick knock-up of yours, there may be errors.

Use a `foreach` instead I think:

```
public function processNewUploads()
{
    $language = OW::getLanguage();
    $osuploadBOL = OSUPLOAD_BOL_Service::getInstance();

    //Loop through each file that was uploaded
    foreach($_FILES as $key => $file){

        $error = $file['error'] ? 
        /*
        if($file['error']){
            $error = $file['error'];
        }else{
            $error = 0;
        }
        */

        //If the user is logged in then get the userId
        if(OW::getUser()->isAuthenticated()) {
            $fileOwner = OW::getUser()->getId();
        } else {
            $fileOwner = 0;
        }

        //Get the IP of the uploader
        $fileOwnerIp = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

        //Get the raw file name
        $rawFileName = $file['name'];

        //Get the unique file name
        $uniqueFileName = uniqid('',true);

        //Get the upload time
        $uploadTimeStamp = time();

        //Get the file extension
        $fileExtension = explode(".", $file['name']);
        $n = count($fileExtension) - 1;
        $fileExtension = '.'.strtolower($fileExtension[$n]);

        //Get the size of the file
        $fileSize = $file['size'];

        //Get the display name of the file
        $fileDisplayName = $rawFileName;

        //Insert the file information into the database
        $sql = 'INSERT INTO ' . OSUPLOAD_BOL_OsuploadDao::getInstance()->getTableName() . " (fileOwner,fileOwnerIp,rawFileName,uniqueFileName,uploadTimeStamp,fileExtension,fileSize,fileDisplayName,error)
        VALUES ('$fileOwner','$fileOwnerIp','$rawFileName','$uniqueFileName.$fileExtension','$uploadTimeStamp','$fileExtension','$fileSize','$fileDisplayName','$error')";

        OW::getDbo()->Insert($sql);

        if(!$error > 0){
            //Move the new upload as long as there was not an error with it
            $fileToMove = $file['tmp_name'];
            $osuploadBOL->moveNewUpload($fileToMove,$uniqueFileName,$fileExtension);
            continue;
        }else{
            //If there was an error just go to the next file
            continue;
        }
    }
}
```